# AvPlayer not playing video in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I've been trying to get this to work but can't seem to find the solution.  I want a video to start playing on viewDidLoad.  I can get the AVPlayerViewController to show up but no video plays.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()

    let videoPath = NSURL(string: "https://youtu.be/dWYNNQdD6rY")


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoPath!)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        playerController.player = player
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)
        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

        player.play()    
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Any error messages? Bugs?

Comment: No error messages.  Just won't play the video.  I've tried several different video URL's and none will play.  Controller shows up fine put when I press the play button the screen just goes black.

Comment: AVPlayer isn't going to play using a link to a YouTube page. You need to give it a link to an actual video file or HLS playlist.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to feed the AVPlayer a URL to either an m3u8 file or directly to a movie. Some [example m3u8 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104301/hls-streaming-video-url-need-for-testing) can be found on Stack Overflow and other websites.
Change your video path to be something like this:

```
let videoPath = NSURL(string: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8")
```